# Bug: I think that the year on this answer is incorrect

Tags: bug, answers

I think that the year on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28071682/109941) is incorrect.

Could someone please investigate? Did I really submit this answer this past January? I thought that I submitted this answer years ago.

Comment: according to the timeline it was this past january, yes: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4566315/timeline

Comment: Also, according this [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/323723/post-details?postId=28071682), it was 2015-01-21 16:05:23.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to both your profile (image below) and the post [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4566315/timeline), you submitted the answer on Jan 21, 2015.

[image: Profile Answer]

---

[You responded to a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566315/my-html-element-has-a-chinese-title-can-jquery-help-me-render-the-tooltip-corre/28071682#comment44522682_4588622) on the same date suggesting that your comment be made an answer. The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566315/my-html-element-has-a-chinese-title-can-jquery-help-me-render-the-tooltip-corre/28071682#comment44515563_4588622) you were responding to was made that day as well:

[image: Comments]